# Why Firebase is not adding up the data to the database ? What's wrong with the Firebase Service code?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-services, angularfire2

I'm working on an Angular + Firebase project. And I'm facing an error while uploading the data over firebase database. Here is my code for 'firebase' service in Angular2.

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireObject, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
  listings ;
  listing: Observable<any[]>;
  folder: any;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.folder = 'listingimages';
   }

  getListings(){
      //this.listings = this.db.list('/listings').valueChanges() as Observable<Listing[]>
      this.listings = this.db.list('/listings').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
        return actions.map(action => ({ key: action.key, ...action.payload.val() }));
      })
      return this.listings;
  }

  getListingDetails(id){
    this.listing = this.db.object('/listings/'+id).valueChanges() as Observable<Listing[]>;
    return this.listing;

  }

  addListing(listing){
    //Create Root Reference     
        let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    for(let selectedFile of [(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('image')).files[0]]){
      let path = `/${this.folder}/${selectedFile.name}`;
      let iRef = storageRef.child(path);
      iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot) => {
        listing.image = selectedFile.name;
        listing.path = path;
        return this.listings.push(listing);

        });
    }
  }

}

interface Listing{
    $key?: string;
    title?: string;
    type?: string;
    image?: string;
    city?: string;
    owner?: string;
    bedrooms?: string
}
```

When I click on the Submit button in HTML Template, 'onAddSubmit' Function is called, which further calls the FirebaseService 'addListing' method.

```
onAddSubmit(){
    let listing = {
        title: this.title,
        owner: this.owner,
        city: this.city,
        price: this.price,
        bedrooms: this.bedrooms,
        type: this.type
    }

    this.firebaseService.addListing(listing);
    //this.router.navigate(['listings']);

  }
```

I am not getting what's wrong with the function definition, but nothing is adding up in the firebase database. Error which shows up while submission is as below : [image]

Thanks.

Comment: by **"uploading data to firebase"** is that in `addListing` method ??

Comment: It seems that `selectedFile` is returning undefined here: `iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot) => {
        listing.image = selectedFile.name;
        listing.path = path;
`
Try to see what's selectedFile returning inside there.